# PHP use php tag in renderd RainTPL

Tags: php, smarty

i'm using rainTpl now and i want to use ajax form in renderd pages but after inserting php tag that show in html format and dont work

**RAINTPL:**

```
<?php echo 'ffff'; ?>

{$value.subject}<br/>
{$value.author}<br/>
{$value.date_time}<br/>
```

**RESULT:**

```
<?php echo 'ffff'; ?>
HELLO
My name
2013-01-01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In normal smarty put everything between smarty php tags:

```
{php}
   global $foo, $bar;
   if($foo == $bar)
   {
       echo "This will be sent to browser";
   }
  // assign a variable to Smarty
  $this->assign("varX", "Toffee");
{/php}
<strong>{$varX}</strong> is my fav ice cream :-)
```

This works for me. Check [this link](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.php.tpl) to see more.

in rainTpl, this works different. They have implemented `raintpl::$php_enabled` in the settings, here is how to configure it:

```
raintpl::configure( "php_enabled", true );
```

By default it's false, if you set php_enabled as true you can use normal php tags `<?php ?>` in your templates.

Comment: @mahdipishguy no you cannot, i've edited my answer on how to do it with rainTpl.